# Stack Overflow logo in QNAP Firmware

Tags: discussion, design

I was setting up a new QNAP NAS today, and imagine my surprise when I saw the Stack Overflow logo in the firmware:

[image]

I realise that it's mirrored and monochrome, but that's still gotta be a no-no, right?

- Location: File Manager > More Action > Background Task
- Model: TS-412
- Firmware: 4.1.0

---

2019 Update: This is definitely the Stack Overflow logo, not something that just looks similar. When Stack revised the logo to change the number of the bars, the qnap implementation of our logo changed too:

Taken from a brand-new QNAP today, firmware Version 4.3.6.0993

[image]

Comment: The real question is why they thought the logo would be a good fit for an option called "Background Task".

Comment: @Bolt, probably because the background service runs tasks by popping them out of a stack.

Comment: This would be something for Stack Exchange to decide if it is something they want to pursue or not. Have you tried [contacting them](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact)?

Comment: It is different, number of stack items, the rounded corners, last item is at 90degs and so on.

Comment: Probably taken it from [this iconset](http://icons8.com/icons/#!/3527/stackoverflow) and reversed it.

Comment: In fact the other two icons both exist in [this set](http://icons8.com/download-huge-windows8-set/) - [Transcode Information](http://icons8.com/icons/#!/805/torrent) and [Properties](http://icons8.com/icons/#!/4796/settings3), so it's a strong possibility.

Comment: If you look closer to that logo, it looks quite similar, but in fact it is different, also besides the mirroring: the topmost "sheet" of the StackOverflow logo is not at right angle, wehreas the QNAP icon is. Anyways, noteing this similarity could rather drive more attention to than it would hurt the community. And I don't think anybody could intermix an unwanted relationship of QNAP to StackOverflow. So keep cool at all!

Comment: Interesting. At first glance it looks like the Stack Overflow logo, but I can see the subtle differences now.

Comment: @abto I think you will find that's more to do with their manipulation of the original and how badly they managed to pixelate it, probably with an auto scale, yuck!

Comment: @abto come on... the logo is _called_ StackOverflow in the icon set with the keywords "Keywords: 
community
computer programming
programmers
stack
professionals
languages
python
jQuery
android
php
javacript
java
programming blog
private website
language-independent
Q A" - you don't need a PhD to figure out what they did here.

Comment: There are other icon packs out there that release brand icons, e.g. Font Awesome. I think such icons can be used when they're intended for linking to said brand: a GitHub icon for a link to GitHub, a Stack Overflow icon for linking to SO. The moment they're used for other stuff, the legality can be questioned.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum it is not proven that they got it from there, there only was an assumption on that by Lankymart. Anyways I noted another difference, the bowl of QNAP's icon apears with rounded corners. Whatever, if we have to argue about such a small icon which is representing an action, fearing it violates some brand rights, we're very much doomed.

Comment: @abto So does icons8 one, what's your point? It is a guess but an educated one based off the fact it's not the only icon that appears in that set from the OPs screenshot.

Comment: @Lenkymart this only tells us that the icons8 one is not the logo from StackOverflow. But you're right, the possibility that the icons came from icons8 is very much likely.

Comment: @abto It's Lankymart. Also did you not notice that the icon on icons8 is called "StackOverflow"? I think Ben may have already mentioned that [above](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270394/stack-overflow-logo-in-qnap-firmware#comment88622_270394).

Comment: Pretty unlikely that SE actually owns the rights to the logo, given that it was created by a volunteer without any kind of contract.  The whereabouts of [Peter Borlace](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/04/logo-design-contest-winner/) look hard to trace.

Comment: @HansPassant according to http://help.99designs.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1554815-how-is-copyright-handled the rights of the winning entry are transferred to the contest holder.

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela It's actually not, the number of "stacks" (6) and the finishing angle (not 90°) are the same, the differences you are straining to see is due to anti aliasing caused by re-sampling the vector to a non-vector format.

Comment: The actual question should be, why did SO copy the logo from QNAP firmware?

Comment: @HansPassant [Here](http://pbdesignsolutions.com/project/stack-overflow/) is the creation of SO logo by Pete Borlace.

Answer (score 37):

These icons all appear to be from [the world's largest
icon pack for Windows 8](http://icons8.com/preview/windows-8-icons/).

> [image: Star] [image: Torrent] [image: StackOverFlow] [image: Settings3]
>
> At the very least they are very generic although interestingly the particular icon in question is labelled "Stackoverflow" and is part of the "Social Networks" category of icons *(the cog icon appears to be different, but they obviously use a little creative licence if they have the vectors)*.
>
> > **IMPORTANT:** I can't state 100% that these icons are the ones in the picture. They could have been made by the company if they have a talented graphics designer, and they could have come from one of multitude of iconset sites out there (increasingly developing for Windows 8 metro style).
>
> Just have a look at this quick search I did on [Icon Finder](https://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=stackoverflow)

---

If we assume they are from [Icons8](http://icons8.com/)...

There does not appear to be any restrictions in using / manipulating these icons especially if they have been paid for.

> **From the [Paid License Section](http://icons8.com/paid-license-99/?variant=1&utm_expid=53194731-6.vq_TbMpsR5Whoarsq9YbSg.1&utm_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Ficons8.com%2Fdownload-huge-windows8-set%2F)** *(On the [Icons8](http://icons8.com/) Website)*
>
> > *Paid license includes unlimited use of the icons within a company without providing credit, and the vector source files*
> >
> > ***Permitted Uses***
> >
> > - *Internet and intranet*
> > - *Desktop and mobile applications*
> > - *Web Templates*
> > - *Print Media, Ads, Merchandise*
> > - *Free-to-edit icons*
> > - *Generate custom icon fonts*

In this instance the company has taken the decision to manipulate the vector by mirroring the icon before using it in their software, which for a paid licence is perfectly acceptable (as far as Icons8 licencing is concerned).

---

**Update** *(From [@ChrisF♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270394/stack-overflow-logo-in-qnap-firmware/270428#comment88612_270428))*

I'm not saying this is right, I'm just giving context for where the icons may have come from.
As @ChrisF♦ points out;

> > *"Just because Icons8 are telling their customers that's it's OK to use the icons without credit doesn't make it right"*

which I completely agree with. It will be up to Stack Overflow to decide whether they want to pursue the matter further, I imagine though that this is common practice especially in icon set creation circles.

In either case, I wouldn't be too hard on QNAP.

Comment: Just because Icons8 are telling their customers that's it's OK to use the icons without credit doesn't make it right. Perhaps SE need to talk to Icons8 rather than QNAP

Comment: As I spotted the Apple logo in there, under Operating Systems, I think it's a fairly safe bet that Icons8 pay very little attention to trademark and copyright law.

Comment: In the context of an Icon Pack, perhaps a fair use argument comes into play?  No idea if you can even do that with a trademark, but I can imagine legitimate reasons to *want* to use the Logos/Computer Hardware/Operating Systems/etc. icons to represent these brands in a consistent style like this pack provides.

Comment: @ChrisF I guess you could say that about every social icon ever used tbh if you really wanted to pursue it like that, I mena the facebook social logo is trademarked as well but I have not yet been sued for using it, nor has SE right?

Comment: ChrisF is right: we can't sell the license to someone's logo. I'm not a lawyer, but afaik the concept of [fair use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) must apply. If you're using the logo as a reference to Stack Overflow, it's one thing; if you use it with no reference to it, it's another thing.

Comment: I agree with @dimo414: it's OK to use the logos if you use them right. It wouldn't be right for Icons8 to sell the icon as an icon representing apple as a fruit. However, it's filed in the category called Logos, and the file name is apple_copyrighted.png when you download the icon pack.

Answer (score 14):

You must admit *anyone* could come up with graphics similar to Stack Overflow's logo for various reasons. I remember seeing nearly 20 years ago when I did some graphics design a graphics that is extremely similar to current Stack Overflow's logo. The design was something related to organizing papers... In fact, I am 100% sure some company specialized in graphics designed something that is the same, or similar to Stack Overflow's logo long before Stack Overflow was made.

We can also debate whether the icon in the "Background Task" is the same as Stack Overflow's logo... - IMHO they are different.

Comment: Right, and as we all know, the background track in *Ice, Ice, Baby* is completely different from that of *Under Pressure*.  There's like an extra note and stuff.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man

Comment: @Brad Werth: No, not straw man. Ice... ice baby. Word to your mother.

Answer (score 14):

> but that's still gotta be a no-no, right?

**If Stack Exchange has trademark rights over the Stack Overflow icon**, they would have grounds for requiring that the icon be removed from that firmware. Note here that QNAP has a US presence and SE is US-based, so my response here is based on US law.

The fact that QNAP has paid for the icon set and has a license from Icons8 is not *sufficient* to absolve QNAP. (If Icons8 got a license *from SE* that allows *them* to license to others is a different matter, but there is no evidence that this is the case.)

The fact that the icon used in the firmware is somewhat different from the icon on SO does not constitute a bar to successfully demonstrating infringement. Trademark infringement occurs even if the presumably infringing logo is somewhat different but would still cause people to think that they are looking at the SO logo. *Similarity* is what the court looks for, not *identity*.

The existence of other older similar logos does not automatically mean that an infringement claim would be invalid. It would depend on how these older logos have been used.

Comment: It's hard to see how this is an infringing use. This is just an icon related to an obscure menu option, not a web site logo, so I don't see how any confusion could result.

Comment: @Gabe when I saw that icon I immediately thought of SO before I even read the option, which is what caused me to do a double-take. Anyway I really want want to bring it to the attention of SE in case they want to do anything with the information. If not, then no skin off my nose.

Comment: At least in the U.S., trademarks are registered for a particular purpose. Even if SO's logo was a registered trademark, it'd be to identify a website/community. Here it's used for a very different purpose - to identify a UI action that has zilch to do with communities, websites, etc. IOW: It's all a false alarm, in the best "but think of the children" style.

Comment: Neither I can find any paid license for QNAP. It doesn't automatically mean they did not pay, but definitely there's no purchase from the company name. Disclosure: I'm the part of Icons8 team.