# Stack Overflow's logo is being used in Clear Linux project's website

Tags: discussion, logo

**Please read before flagging as duplicate:** [Stack Overflow logo used on another site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327004/stack-overflow-logo-used-on-another-site) talks about the old logo and a different website. This is with the new logo.

I've been looking at some benchmarks until I found about Clear Linux.

I went to the project's website, and as soon as I scroll to the AutoFDO section, I got surprised by seeing this:

[image: Screenshot of a phone showing the Clear Linux Project's website, focusing on the AutoFDO section, which contains a clone of the Stack Overflow logo.]

Yes, that's an exact copy of the Stack Overflow logo. 5 rectangles, same positions and same container size.

This could happen on minor websites, but on a website belonging to a major corporation... (which must have good web designers)

Has Intel requested permission to use this logo? Or is it allowed to use it (Wikipedia claims public domain status on the logo)? I don't see attribution placed anywhere.

Comment: It's certainly not fair use - but it looks like it could have been a mistake. The official project page doesn't sport a logo at all.

Comment: They are using Font Awesome. Maybe they're living under a rock and mistook `fa-stack-overflow` to mean a literal call stack overflow?

Comment: Related: [Stack Overflow logo in QNAP Firmware](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270394/176646)

Comment: `fa-stack-overflow` is in the brand category, ffs.

Comment: Lack of copyright, i.e. public domain, is not the same as lack of trademark. There's a whole huge collection of images at http://www.brandsoftheworld.com/, most of which are trademarked.

Comment: There was or is another much longer thread on basically the same topic but with a different website/company. Basically SO does not own and did not invent a icon of a stack of paper. The version of it that SO owns includes the specific colors and the name "stackoverflow". This distro made there's blue and white and it doesn't say "stackoverflow". More power to them; it's different enough. Not to mention that there being a Font Awesome SO style paperstack means that (a) you can well expect to see any number of people using it (b) we are letting the public use that part of the logo/icon at will.

Comment: I dunno the heck about that right now but.. Isn't the Stack overflow logo kinda colory?

Comment: @MarkRansom, the legal bar for trademark infringement is higher than the bar for copyright infringement. Does the use of the "stack of paper" logo on that page mislead the average person into thinking SO is involved with Clear Linux, or the "AutoFDO" feature? Probably not...

Comment: Oh, and that's the JSFiddle logo, next to the "Cloud Integrated Advanced Orchestrator" title. `fa fa-jsfiddle`.

Comment: I'd think that if font awesome is free, using any icons from their font does not require attribution. It specifically says there "free for personal and commercial use". If SO has an issue with that, the complaint should be directed at FA folks.

Comment: @Neolisk see what Jon Harper posted below - FA includes brand icons, yes, and they are free for personal and commercial use, yes, but they are supposed to be used in relation to the specific brand or property they represent. So you can't use the twitter icon on a bird-watching page to represent your own content, just because it's free.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy: Ok so basically I can use brand icons to refer to a corresponding website / brand, like Stack Overflow score or number of posts on Twitter in the last week. Do they say it in writing somewhere ? Just curious.

Comment: @Neolisk Exactly. It's on the FontAwesome icons page, and in their licensing terms that Jon Harper linked below.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy: My bad, I thought you were referring to below answer by Travis. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: This shouldn't be allowed right? Can a moderator please clarify with this. Please...

Comment: I don't really have a coherent update to give here since I don't normally handle these issues, but I just wanted to say that we're aware and looking into what's what.

Comment: Guys, consult a lawyer. Laws aren't are as you may presuppose

Comment: @AdamLear any progress on this? It's been 6-8 weeks and the site seems unchanged.

Answer (score 38):

This is a misuse of the [Font Awesome licensing terms](http://fontawesome.io/license/).

Quote (emphasis mine):

> - All brand icons are trademarks of their respective owners.
> - The use of these trademarks does not indicate endorsement of the trademark holder by Font Awesome, nor vice versa.
> - **Brand icons should only be used to represent the company or product to which they refer.**

I would imagine both SO and Font Awesome should take issue with this.

Answer (score 28):

I was able to reproduce this, the image can be found here: https://clearlinux.org/ by clinking on the "show more" button twice.

It would have been nice if the link with the image had actually navigated to Stack Overflow, since that could be related, but it didn't. It goes here: https://clearlinux.org/features/autofdo

Regardless, these matters are best handled by letting the team know, and you could argue that meta is a place for that. Sometimes reaching out on meta also has the added benefit of reaching one of these companies.

If you come across something like this, in order for it to be forcefully removed the team needs to lawyer the s*&^ out of it, which is a huge pain. As a result, it is best to send them an message using the "contact us" form. There is a link at the bottom of every page and I think they all end up at the same place.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact

Comment: This is being used out of font awesome.

Comment: They appear to have just select icons on how they look as they are also breaking the trademark of several others by including the icons of JSFiddle and Sellsy from Font Awesome.